# Reactjs - Can't base64 encode file from react-dropzone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, base64

I am using `react-dropzone` to handle file upload on my website. When successfully loading a file, the dropzone triggers the following callback:

```
onDrop: function (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) {
  myFile = acceptedFiles[0];
  console.log('Accepted files: ', myFile);
}
```

I would like to base64 encode this file. When doing :

```
var base64data = Base64.encode(myFile)
console.log("base64 data: ", base64data) // => base64 data: W29iamVjdCBGaWxlXQ==W29iamVjdCBGaWxlXQ==
```

Regardless of file uploaded, it always prints out the same string.

Am I missing something ? I need to base64 encode this file (always images)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This JS Bin is a working example of converting a File to base64: http://jsbin.com/piqiqecuxo/1/edit?js,console,output . The main addition seems to be reading the file using a `FileReader`, where `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` returns a base64 encoded string

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var files = document.getElementById('file').files;
  if (files.length > 0) {
    getBase64(files[0]);
  }
});

function getBase64(file) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     console.log(reader.result);
   };
   reader.onerror = function (error) {
     console.log('Error: ', error);
   };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it in a neat method that works with async / await, you can do it this way

```
const getBase64 = async (file: Blob): Promise<string | undefined> => {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file as Blob);

  return new Promise((reslove, reject) => {
    reader.onload = () => reslove(reader.result as any);
    reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
  })
}
```

Comment: get rid of the while loop and construct a new Promise, also it is tagged javascript not typescript

Comment: getting result as [[PromiseResult]] how to fetch promise result

Comment: my code as 
const files = acceptedFiles.map(file =>
        Object.assign(file, {
          preview: URL.createObjectURL(file),
          file:getBase64(file).then(function(response) {
            return response;
          })
          .catch(error => console.error(error)),
        })
      );

Answer (score 0):

#### Convert to base64 using Base64

Base on your code I will recommend using the helper functions [atob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/atob) to decode and [btoa()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/btoa) to encode to base64 for more details [click here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-encode-and-decode-strings-with-base64-in-javascript)
Example

```
let base64data = btoa(stringToEncode)
```

Below is a sample of what you requested using **FileReader()** instead *(this is something I have worked on)*.

#### Using FileReader in Reactjs component with react-dropzone

To get the content of the file reader in react I used the callback function to update the state as used in the *MDN Web docs*.

#### React component

```js
// state to store the base64 data
const [base64File, setbase64File] = useState(null);

// Create the callback function
const base64Callback = async (err, res) => {
    if (!err) {
      setbase64File(res); // setting the state is the important part 
    } else {
      setbase64File(null);
    }
  };

// call function to convert to base64
onDrop: function (acceptedFiles, rejectedFiles) {
  myFile = acceptedFiles[0];
  getBase64(myFile, base64Callback);

  console.log('Accepted files: ', myFile);
}
```

#### Function to convert to base64

```js
async function getBase64(file, callback) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => callback(null, reader.result);
  reader.onerror = (error) => callback(error);
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

export default getBase64;
```

The above code is a modified version of code from the MDN Web docs site [click for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result)